# Error with routes in Laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem when I use routes in Laravel 5.0, I only need to call this route:

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

But the browser shows me this, when I write http://localhost/course/public/home:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /course/public/home was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

If I write http://localhost/course/public/
the index works but the other routes doesn't work, I don't know why.

In my Routes.php I have this:

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

I only downloaded laravel 5.0 with composer, I did not change nothing in the code after the download, I only want to test the routes and these don't work.

Thaks for your help.

Comment: Is there a controller named "public"?

Comment: Hello   Gaurav Dave, the controller's name is "HomeController", public is the folder where the index is located.

Comment: Remove public from the url and go to /course/home instead

Comment: I did it but the error is the same.

Comment: Try  http://localhost/course/public/index.php/home

Comment: Thanks RobyMi! the route worked like you said, but why this is happening?  In my routes.php I have this:  Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
 'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
 'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Answer (score 0):

in conclusion (the comments solved the problem, so thank you guys for this!!) you probably run Laravel on Apache and you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled... or not configured correctly.

Laravel works with so called pretty urls. In order to achieve this, every request is rewritten and the config you can find in the .htaccess file in the public folder. This to give a quick and dirty explanation will let you write URLs without the `index.php`.

Additionally your server should serve the public folder and not the main folder. That's a security thing if you want to use your site in production.

Alternatively you can use nginx which in my opinion is a lot easier to configure and if you run `laravel homestead` everything comes straight out of the box.